# NOT NULL constraint failed in SQLIte and EF

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a `NOT NULL constraint failed` issue with SQLite. I am using NET 5.0 and EF Core

This fails

```
var settingsDal = new DalCf.Settings();
dc.Settings.Add(settingsDal);
settingsDal = GetUpdatedSettings();
await DataAccess.Save(dc);
```

This code works

```
var settingsDal = new DalCf.Settings();
settingsDal = GetUpdatedSettings(); //swapped
dc.Settings.Add(settingsDal);       //swapped
await DataAccess.Save(dc);
```

I don't understand why. I would have thought that adding `settingsDal` to the List doesn't sever the reference?

Answer (score 0):

`GetUpdatedSettings()` returns a new object and with:

```
settingsDal = GetUpdatedSettings();
```

`settingsDal` refers to that new object.

It is not the same as the one defined here:

```
var settingsDal = new DalCf.Settings();
```

which was previously added to the list with:

```
dc.Settings.Add(settingsDal);
```

So, when the code reaches the line:

```
await DataAccess.Save(dc);
```

the list does not contain the object that `GetUpdatedSettings()` returned.